# ASP.NET Core model not binding to the controller via AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-post, model-binding

I have read on so many forums that a lot of times model won't bind to the controller due to the parameter of the action has the same name of a field but I changed it to a unique names and I am still not getting it. 
I am passing the objects after obtaining them from the html pages and using JSON.Stringify to serialize it and everything looks perfect in the 'Payload request' if I debug it in chrome tool but as soon as it hits the controller, the model is null. what is wrong with the code?

Model:

```
public class JsonFileModel
  {
     public string[] Geo { get; set; }
public string[] State { get; set; }

public string[] Variables { get; set; }

public int[] Weights { get; set; }
public string[] Variable_Category { get; set; }

public string UID { get; set; }
```

}

AJAX Call:

```
  var geo_graphic_level = $('input[name=geographic-radio-name]:checked').val();
    var state = $('#states-select-id option:selected').val();
    var v = $('#variable-list-select-id option:selected');
    var variables = [];
    var json = "'" + JSON.stringify(variables) + "'";
    $(v).each(function (index, v) {
        variables.push($(this).val())
    });
    var variable_category = $('#categories-select-id option:selected').val();
    var weights = [];
    $("input[name='weight-name']").each(function () {

        weights.push(this.value);

    });
```

//the above code gives the values for the objects

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Drive")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Geo: geo,
            State: state,
            Variables: variables,
            Weights: weights,
            Variable_Category: variable_category
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save([FromBody] JsonFileModel d)
    {
        //code code 
        return Json("worked");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well so I defined my properties wrong for example when I am only expecting string from Geo, I defined my model to expect [] array. After fixing it, everything is working perfect!

Comment: For anyone else, I was missing [FromBody]